# Question regarding COC Wartime troop upgradation

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am upgrading my troops for war tomorrow. The upgrade will be completed tomorrow but by this time I will be at war with another clan. So can I use these upgraded troops during war?

Comment: Yes you can.. All troup which are under update and will complete in middle of war then you can use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Leo the Lion said, you will be able to use the troops with a higher level. To expand, unlike defense and defending hero levels in your war base, troop level and hero level when attacking is independent of war. Whatever level your troops are when you click attack, that is the level they will be when your attack starts regardless of what type of attack it is (multiplayer, single player, or clan war).

Comment: Ok thanks. But its a shame that I cannot vote any answer up as I am still new. And what about the upgraded building! Is it upgraded automatically as well !

Comment: @MdMehmudSiddiqueTwin if a building is upgrading during war, and doesn't finish before prep day finishes, they will be functional in your war base, but they will not be upgraded. If you are building a new building, it will also be functional in your war base, and it will be level 1. hope that helps, and if this did help, you can click the little check box to mark it as an answer, so others will know this is the answer. and when you get enough rep, you can always go back and upvote helpful answers

Comment: Agree with Dragonrage that only troops will get updated but not the buildings. They will have same level till war and as war will end, building will upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to remember, is that:

1. all troops you use will be the level they will enter the battlefield, and
2. your base will not change during the battle day as soon as the preparation day ends.

What the above mean for you is that:

- if the troops you are going to make your attacks with are having upgrades on battle day, they will be the level they appear as after upgrading (what you see is what you get).
- if you have troops in your CC (Clan Castle), or your heroes, or defenses in your war base were upgrading during preparation day and completes the upgrade during battle day, they will not be the level they are after upgrade. However, if the upgrade completes during preparation day (battle day has not begun yet), then they will take the upgraded level during battle day.

The only exception is for buildings/traps that begun construction (*not upgrade*) before battle day. These will appear as level 1 during battle day.

Examples:

- A player puts lv4 archers in their clanmates' war CC. That player has his archers complete upgrade during battle day. On battle day, the war CC will have archer lv4.
- If a player has lv4 archers upgrading and attacks with them before the upgrade completes, they will be lv4. If he attacks after the upgrade, they will be lv5.
- A player begins building 1 X-Bow and has 2 X-Bows upgrading to lv2 during preparation day. Of the 2 upgrading X-Bows, the first completes during battle day and the second after battle day. The war base will have 3 operational lv1 X-Bows, because at the moment the battle day begun, the base had 2 lv1 X-Bows and 1 X-Bow under construction, or tl;dr:

  ```
  --------------------------------------------
  X-Bow   | Prep Day        | Battle Day     
  --------+-----------------+-----------------
  X-Bow 1 | Lv1 in war base | Lv1 in war base
  --------+-----------------+-----------------
  X-Bow 2 | Lv1 in war base | Lv1 in war base
  --------+-----------------+-----------------
  X-Bow 3 | Lv2 in war base | Lv2 in war base
  --------------------------------------------
  ```

  X-Bow 1's contruction does not complete during either days.
  X-Bow 2's upgrade does not complete before battle day begins.
  X-Bow 3's upgrade completes during preperation day.

Comment: you examples are somewhat confusing to understand. the first one sounds like you are saying if i donate troops before a troop upgrade finishes, the troops will be upgraded once my upgrade finishes, which would be incorrect. the second example, while accurate, could be worded better to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Dragonrage I never meant it to be that way, but wanted as few examples as possible. I guess I've no choice if I want to cover everything...